# Change a model object value with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models

So I have a model that has a FloatField, also I have a javascript code, what I need is to change the value of the Floatfield with +1 everytime you click in a button, the problem is that I had no idea of how to make it, here is my model:

```
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    """
    Profile model
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')
    notifications = models.FloatField(default='0')
```

I need to give +1 to notifications object evertime a function in js is doing, how can I do this?

Comment: you need to implement a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#writing-views) to make this change. Using JS, you can send an AJAX to this view.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf okey, but how can I do that, can you post an answer please?